# What happened to the Fixed_precision_nt number type in CGAL?

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal, fixed-point

Does anyone know why [Fixed_precision_nt](https://doc.cgal.org/Manual/3.1/doc_html/cgal_manual/NumberTypeSupport_ref/Class_Fixed_precision_nt.html#Cross_link_anchor_1354) was removed from recent versions of CGAL (or is it there and I just can't find it?)

Comment: The removal happened in July 2006, and the current developper's mailing list started in August 2006 :-( I don't know where to find archives of the previous list. Fixed_precision_nt was not so convenient to use, and the performance advantage over double had become too small I guess.

Comment: @MarcGlisse it's not about performance over double, it's about robustness.

Comment: CGAL is at least as robust with double as with Fixed_precision_nt, if you use the Epick kernel (internally, CGAL may use intervals or rationals where needed). What makes you think Fixed_precision_nt is more robust?

Comment: I expected it to be faster than Epick by a long way and probably faster than double at the expense of accuracy, while still being robust because fixed point integer calculations are more mathematically pure than floating point in that a x b = b x a as long as you account for for overflow.  Epick is far too slow in many instances for doing Boolean operations for example.

Answer (score 0):

It got removed 9 yeears ago. See the [enter link description here](https://www.cgal.org/2007/06/01/cgal-33/)

Comment: Yeah, but why?!  It seems like it would be very useful if I understand what it does.  Sometimes you just want fast robust algorithms and 24 bits of precision is plenty.